# phonegap 2.0 sql SELECT in iPad simulator

Tags: sql, ipad, select, cordova, simulator

I have a test phonegap app to try sql database querying using Osx Lion, Xcode 4.3.3, phonegap 2.0, almost like in the docs

```
function populateDB(tx,user) {
 tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER');
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (id unique, data text)');
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USER (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
 alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function successCB() {
 alert("success!");
}

function queryDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USER', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx,result) {
 if(results.rows.length==0) alert("No users");
 else alert(results.rows.length);
}

var db = window.openDatabase("user", "1.0", "user", 200000);

db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
```

The second transaction is giving an error: "Error processing SQL:[object SQLerror]"

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you querySuccess- callback you have

```
if(results)
```

and in the function parameter it reads

```
querySuccess(tx,result).
```

After fixing that the code ran normally in Chrome's console.